# Circles with many points from an additive subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^2.$

Tags: nt.number-theory, discrete-geometry, additive-combinatorics

Given a point set in the plane, defined by three distinct, non-zero vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3\in \mathbb{R}^2.$
$$L_n=\{a_1v_1+a_2v_2+a_3v_3 | a_1,a_2,a_3\in\{0,1,\ldots,n\}\}$$ What is the largest possible number of points of $L_n$ on a circle?

It should be $n^{o(1)},$ but I don't know how to prove it. If we had two vectors only, then the statement is true, the largest intersection with a circle is $n^\varepsilon$ (where $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$), but it would be still very interesting to see a simple proof for that.

Comment: Three vectors in the plane are necessarily dependent, and any lattice in the plane has rank at most two.

Comment: @Stanley Yao Xiao: I guess the OP means "subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^2$" instead of "lattice" — then the question makes sense.

Comment: @Stanley Yao Xiao: I edited the question removing the word lattice. Thanks abx.

Comment: For $v_2=v_3=0$ you get $n^2$. If you allow circles with radius 0 you can even get $n^3$. I think you should specify reasonable conditions for the $v_i$ .

Comment: @KarlFabian $L_n$ is a set of points. If two vectors are zero then it is a set of $n$ collinear points with at most two points of intersection with any circle.